# How to calculate time complexity of a looping algorithm using simple steps?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have following piece of code and I am completely lost to find the time complexity of this looping structure. Actually it is from Quicksort and I've read that this looping structure has complexity O(n) but I am unable to understand it.
Infact I can't understand how to calculate complexity of loops specially while loop where some true false conditions are met other than simple increment or decrement conditions.

```
while (i <= j) {
        while (array[i] < somevalue)
              i++;
        while (array[j] > somevalue)
              j--;
        if (i <= j) {
             #do something
              i++;
              j--;
        }

  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complexity of this loop is roughly number of times `#do something` is called.

In the worst case, neither `array[i] < somevalue` nor `array[j] < somevalue` will be true at any iteration. Then `#do something` will be called `N/2` times (rounded one way or another -- doesn't matter in this case), assuming `i+j = N` when we enter the loop.

It's `N/2` because we descrease upper and increase lower bound simultaneously, essentially making steps of size 2.

So, the time complexity is `O(N/2)` which is the same as `O(N)`.

Comment: Thank you. I think I got it.

Answer (score 0):

`O(N)` because `i+j = N` when their value meet or cross over each other.

The loop breaks once `i` and `j` eventually meet in such way that `(i <= j)` becomes false.

```
i ->                               <- j

<------------------N------------------->
```

Comment: what about inner loops?

Comment: Your code is somewhat incorrect. It can lead to array index out of bound access. You must check `i < the size of array` and `j >= 0`.